# i want to load facebook Interstitial Ad every five minutes in ios(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

i added below code in viewdidload method

```
self.interstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd.init(placementID: "")
self.interstitialAd.delegate = self;
interstitialAd.load()
```

and call time for every five minutes to load  ad

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 300.0, target: self, selector: #selector(callInterstitialAdEveryFiveMinutes), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
@objc func callInterstitialAdEveryFiveMinutes()  {
    interstitialAd.load()
}
```

but not showing ad every five minutes and give error 
7000 your ad is already load

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you should **first** close the loaded ad and request a new one:

> Do not call loadAd on the FBInterstitialAd while the ad is being shown on the screen. If you need to load another FBInterstitialAd for future use, you can do so after the user closed the current one, for example in the interstitialAdDidClose callback.

So in this case, you'd need to wait till the user closes the first ad:

```
func interstitialAdDidClose(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd?) {
    print("Interstitial had been closed")
    // Consider to add code here to resume your app's flow

   // .. Schedule the timer, or show another ad .. //

}
```

Please read: 
[Adding Interstitial Ad to your iOS app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios-interstitial/)

Or see this question [InterstitialAd failed to load with error?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=164143154025724):

> The error you were receiving is basically we can't match a Facebook profile to deliver relevant ads.

Comment: i already first ad close but not getting second ad while calling function

Comment: Well that tells you one thing in particular, there might be a specific timer till you can load a new one

Comment: Yes , every 5 minutes i want to load ad but getting error 7000 as describe in question

Comment: The error you were receiving is basically we can't match a Facebook profile to deliver relevant ads.

then why show first time and afterward give error already load ad

and already development as per facebook doc

Answer (score 0):

In timer, place this code

```
func showInter() {
        if self.fullSscreenAd.isAdValid {
            self.fullSscreenAd.show(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }
```

when the first ad is closed, load the interstitial ad so that the load is ready for the next ad.

```
func interstitialAdDidClose(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
         self.loadinter() }

func loadinter() {
        fullSscreenAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "your placement id")
        fullSscreenAd.delegate = self
        fullSscreenAd.load()
    }
```